# ¿Como validar que después de un ultimo carácter me tome el resultado (PHP)?

Tags: php

En `php` estoy recibiendo una `URL` que concatena el titulo de una publicación con un identificador.
Eje: **www.midominio.com/post/ultimas-noticias-empresariales-6BEDRCT94014R**

Quisiera obtener únicamente ese identificador (6BEDRCT94014R) una vez se haya  redirigido a dicha ruta.

intente el siguiente código, el cual valido que si existe un guion(-) me tome lo que sigue, pero resulta que como el titulo por publicación puede cambiar entonces pueden existir muchos o pocos guiones.

**$str = substr($id_post, strrpos($id_post, '-') + 1);**

> La idea es que siempre me tome el identificador que esta después del
>   ultimo guion.

Agradecería la colaboración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando explode asi:

```
$str = explode('-', $id_post);
$id = end($str);
```

Comment: excelente, muchas gracias.